# Results missing using IE9 with datatables serverside

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, datatables

Ok, this is weird and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
I am the creator of LogZilla (a syslog management/reporting tool).
One of my users has pointed out a bug that only exists in IE9. IE 8 and below has never worked properly so I can live with that. But IE9 should be working. FWIW, I am running IE10 and it works. But if I put it in IE9 mode it doesn't.

If you visit my [demo server](http://demo.logzilla.net) and do a search (just click the search button at the bottom of the page after logging in), you can see that the data is presented properly using Chrome and FF and IE10, but if you use IE9 it says there is no data to display.

I've also noticed that if you use a GET instead of a POST it works properly. The results page after a search has a small disk icon at the top right - if you click that you can get the full URL to paste as a GET.

I'm wondering if the problem is [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/700/server-side-processing-hangs-at-loading-data-from-server/p1) which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146268/json-stringify-and-json-parse-not-working-in-ie9), but I have tried loading json2.js in the header and it doesn't fix anything (maybe I did it wrong?)

Edit: I also though Modernizr might help, but I have no clue how to implement it, and the [download page](http://modernizr.com/download/) is insanely confusing - which options do I need?

Edit: Based on @thatidiotguy's comment, I checked my source and it is actually using a GET, not a POST. So now I'm even more confused as to why pasting the url works when clicking the button from the main page doesn't?

Comment: Why are you retrieving information for a search with a POST anyway? In regards to your issue, you are going to have to provide some code that is not working exactly. No one is goign to sift through your whole web site code.

Comment: Happy to, which code do I need to post? The ajax? The datatables code? the html?

Comment: re: POST, see my second edit above. I was mistaken.

Comment: What I mean is that you are going to have to find the code that does the request, and the code that displays the result. If you are indeed using a GET, you should be able to put the url into your browser and get the same information back. If that works, then you know it is the presentation code.

Comment: It is a GET, but when I paste the same thing, that works. I've also noticed that if I put the browser in IE9 "quirks" mode, then that works too.

Comment: I have to see code to help you further. Right now I am doing the debugging for you. You do that part, I will try and help out with what code changes you need to make. Figure out whether it is the actual AJAX call, or if its the presentation of said data afterwards. Then post the relevant code in your question.