# How can I use JSON.parse in a bookmarklet in IE9 if the page is not in standards mode?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm creating a bookmarklet that will accept a JSON string through a prompt like so:

`prompt("Enter your JSON", "");`

Once they enter their JSON string, I convert their string into a JSON Object using `JSON.parse`. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell `JSON.parse` is not supported in IE9. The object of my bookmarklet is to loop through the available `<input>`'s on the page and fill their values with data from my JSON object.

What can I do in order to get this to work in IE9?

One possible solution - This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146404/556079 suggests that `JSON.parse` will work if my document is in standards mode. Since this is a bookmarklet, I have no control over the doctype of the page. Would it be possible to change the doctype using my bookmarklet?

I would prefer to avoid loading libraries in my bookmarklet like http://bestiejs.github.io/json3. If this can be done without resorting to that, that would be ideal.

Alternatively, the input doesn't need to even be a JSON. I just need to get some user submitted data into a loop where I can reference anywhere between 2 and 50 values.

Comment: Try having your bookmarklet load a JSON library like http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Comment: P.S. With standards mode, `JSON.parse` works in IE8+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=json

Comment: I'm confused as to why my question is being voted to be closed. The suggested duplicate question does not answer my question.

Comment: I re-opened it.  It was probably closed since that is a possible solution, though not the one you are looking for.

Comment: "The input doesn't need to even be a JSON. I just need to get some user submitted data into a loop where I can reference anywhere between 2 and 50 values." In that case, make your own format, with its own parser (regex or whatever).  Let users know how to enter in the data.

Comment: If it's a bookmarklet - I'd probably just do `eval('(' + strData + ')')` *hides*

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You know, I didn't even think of that.  `eval` just never crosses my mind.  Though here, it might be a fine solution.

Comment: Right now my users would submit a JSON string like this `[{"name":"Example","url":"http://example.com"}]`. Then I would loop through it to get the values. If `eval()` is a suitable replacement for `JSON.parse` I'll look into it as I've never used `eval()` before.

Comment: @jimmykup: Before `JSON.parse` was widely supported, `eval('(' + strData + ')')` was used.