# How do I stop IE9 automatically going into compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I've been working on this for a few hours and still no joy. I'm working on IE9.

I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I also have the document mode on IE8 set by:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

This resultsin IE8 for the document mode (good) but it results in the browser mode automatically going into compatibility mode which mucks the website up.

What do I need to change to stop IE9 defaulting to compatibility mode when loading the page for a visitor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722085/ie8-browser-mode-standards-mode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website)

Answer (score 1):

Use the meta tag whit this way:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

IE=EmulateIE7. Specify IE=5, IE=7, IE=8, or IE=9

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This does not work as it still puts IE 9 into compatibility mode and the document mode is IE9, which is not what I want. I need IE8.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a web-server, add `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` HTTP response header instead of the corresponding `<meta>` tag to switch to latest standards and disable the compatibility mode button.

If your code is standard enough, IE won't switch to compatibility. Run through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to verify this.